# Package Maven Plugin specific config as a "pre-configured" plugin dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Suppose I have a lengthy, complex Maven Plugin configuration which I use in multiple projects, not necessarily related.

For example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Lengthy complex replacement rules -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

For related modules, I understand this config could go in the parent `pom.xml`.

But short of creating my own Maven plugin ( perhaps using `mojo-executor`? ) is there a way to package this as an independent dependency which could be referenced by any arbitrary project which wanted to use this exact specific config?

Comment: With dependencies, this is typically done through a BOM. For plugins, I don't think this is possible. [Relevant Nabble thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/import-plugin-configurations-td5741927.html)